# SQL only accepts my input if I leave the Category and Brand blank

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello I am trying to master php css and html by building an Ecommerce website. Whenever I input all the fields required to submit it to the database, the page just refreshes. but when I leave the Category and Brand blank (which the default is select a category / brand) the database will accept it. I've been at it for hours and I my head hurts a lot now. Here is my code:

insert_product.php

```
<form action="insert_product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <table align="center" width="700" border="2" bgcolor="orange">

                <tr align="center">
                    <td colspan="7"><h2>Insert New Post Here</h2></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Title:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product_title" size="60" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Category</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="product_cat" >
                        <option>Select a Category</option>
                            <?php
                            //calls the database in Category List

                            $get_cats = "select * from categories";

                            $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

                            while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
                            $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
                            $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];

                            echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Brand</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="product_brand" >
                        <option>Select a Brand</option>
                            <?php
                            //copy pasted and edited from getcats

                            $get_brands = "select * from brands";

                            $run_brands = mysqli_query($con, $get_brands); //see $con above and getbrand (executing query)

                            while ($row_brands = mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){ //loop fetching data or query + saving record in row brands

                            $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
                            $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title']; //fetches brand id and title from the table


                            echo "<option value=$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>"; //connected to ul id="brands"
                        }

                        ?>
                        </select>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Image</b></td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="product_image" required/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Price</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product_price" required/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Description</b></td>
                    <td><textarea name="product_desc" cols="20" rows="10" ></textarea></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Keywords</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product_keywords" size="50" required/></td>
                </tr>


                <tr align="center">
                    <td colspan="7"><input type="submit" name="insert_post" value="Insert Product Now" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

</body>

</html>

<?php
    //If insert post is clicked, it will accept the data inputted
    if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])){

            $product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
            $product_cat = $_POST['product_cat'];
            $product_brand = $_POST['product_brand'];
            $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
            $product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
            $product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];

            //getting the image file
            $product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
            $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];

            move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"product_images/product_image");


            $insert_product = "insert into products (product_cat,product_brand,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords) values ('$product_cat','$product_brand','$product_title','$product_price','$product_desc','$product_image','$product_keywords')";

            $insert_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);

            if($insert_pro) {

            echo "<script>alert('Product has been inserted!')</script>";
            echo "<script>windows.open('insert_product.php','_self')</script>";
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Update: I found out the problem was the Brand field. Because when I leave the Brand field blank, the data submits to the database. although im still scratching my head debugging the brand code

Comment: haha nevermind i figured it out:

echo "<option value=$brand_id'>

forgot to add ' on the brand_id

guess i just have poor eyesight

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's my first time answering:

```
 <select name="product_brand" >
                        <option>Select a Brand</option>
                            <?php
                            //copy pasted and edited from getcats

                            $get_brands = "select * from brands";

                            $run_brands = mysqli_query($con, $get_brands); //see $con above and getbrand (executing query)

                            while ($row_brands = mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){ //loop fetching data or query + saving record in row brands

                            $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
                            $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title']; //fetches brand id and title from the table


                            echo "<option value=$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>"; //connected to ul id="brands"
                        }
```

the problem is that I forgot to put a single apostrophe in the $brand_id variable.